# Check if class is filled jQuery

Tags: jquery, class, input

I have a question regarding a javascript check.

I have the following form

```
<form name='form' id='form' method='post' action='next.php'>

<input type='text' class='red'  />
<input type='text' class='red'  />
<input type='text' class='red'  />
<input type='text' class='blue' />
<input type='text' class='blue' />
<input type='submit' value='Next' />

</form>
```

What I want to accomplish is that the form can only be submitted if either one of the fields with the class 'red' is filled. So if the user only fills in one or more of the class 'blue' fields, they get an alert that they need to put in at least one class 'red' field as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$('#form').submit(function(){
    var valid = $(this).find('input.red').filter(function(){
        return $.trim(this.value) != '';
    }).length > 0;
    if(!valid){
        alert('fill red');
        return false;
    }

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5Sj38/)

Comment: what about a .red input filled with spaces? ;)

Comment: @roasted we can use `$.trim()`

Answer (score 1):

You can hook up to the submit event of the form and in that iterate over all fields with the class red and tehn return the result. If the submit event returns false the form wonøt be submitted

```
$("#form").submit(function(){
   var exist = false;
   $(this).find("input.red").each(function(){
          exist = exist || this.value;
   });
   return exist;
})
```

this assumes that an all whitespace value should be treated as a filled in field. If it should not you need to `.trim()` the value.

A version could be made to exit early when exist is set to true but it's unlikely to be significantly quicker for a low number of elements

Comment: Your answer is the most complete here, nice to handle both case with or without `trim`  +1

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    var exist ;

    $("#formId input[type=text]").each(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('red')) 
         if($(this).val() != "") 
            exist = true;             
    });

    if(exist == true) {
        // red class exist
    } else {
        alert("No Red Class");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't understand OP's question like this

Comment: you are not checking for any value and aren't handling the submit event. The form can be submitted without the submit buttoned being clicked

Comment: @RuneFS i am checking exist value

Comment: @RuneFS what i am not cheling

Comment: filling means not giving value

Comment: eaxctly you are checking whether a field exist but OP wants to check if they are filled (Ie have something filled into them aka has a value) not if they are part of the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to acheive?

```
  var failed = false;
  $(".red").each(function(i, elem){
     if($(elem).val() == ""){
        failed = true;
        return false;
     }
  });

  if (failed){
  //don't proceed
  }
```

It wont proceed if one of the inputs with class `red` is *empty string*

Answer (score 0):

You seems to want to check if at least one `.red` input is filled:

```
$("#form").submit(function() {
    if($(this).find('.red').filter(function(){return $.trim(this.value) != ""}).length === 0)
       return false;        
});
```

Comment: OP only says not filled that might or might not imply that an all white space string should be disregarded

Comment: It's up to OP to choice ;)

Comment: I agree but since your code chooses for him I merely suggest to mention _your_ choice on his behalf explictly

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('input[type=submit]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var check = $('.red').filter(function() {
        return this.value != ''
    }).length;

    if(check < 1){
     alert('Fill out red class input')   
    }
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/n4WZ3/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

For your use-case, use something like:

```
$("#form").submit(function () {
    if ($(this).find('.red').filter(function () {
                return $.trim(this.value) != ""
            }).length === 0)
        return false;
});
```